# cout is only working after gets() eventhough i had written it before gets()

Tags: c++, string, cout, gets

I have just started learning c++.
I wrote this program for finding how many vowels in a  sentence.
But when i run the program it asking for input before the cout and cout is working after `gets()`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char str[50];
    int vow;
    cout<<"Type a sentence";
    gets(str);
    for(int i=0; str[i]!='\0';i++){
        switch(str[i]){
        case 'a':
        case 'e':
        case 'i':
        case 'o':
        case 'u': vow++;
        }
    }
    cout<<"There are "<<vow<<" vowels in the string "<<str;
    return 0;

}
```

output

```
hello world
Type a sentenceThere are 3 vowels in the string hello world
```

Comment: *never* use `gets`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `std::cout` is buffered, and you are not flushing the buffer to the console before calling `gets()`, which has no concept of `std::cout` or its buffer.  So, you will have to flush the buffer manually, either by writing a `'\n'` character to the output, eg:

```
cout << "Type a sentence\n";
gets(str);
```

Or, using the `std::endl` or `std::flush` manipulator:

```
cout << "Type a sentence" << endl; // writes '\n' and then flushes
gets(str);
```

```
cout << "Type a sentence" << flush; // just flushes without writing '\n' first
gets(str);
```

Or, calling the `std::cout.flush()` method directly, eg:

```
cout << "Type a sentence";
cout.flush();
gets(str);
```

But, you really should not be mixing C-style I/O and C++-stye I/O. `std::cin` and `std::cout` are [`tie()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/tie)'d together by default, so if you had used `std::cin` instead of `gets()` to read the input, then `std::cin` would have first flushed `std::cout`'s buffer automatically.

Try this instead:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   char str[50] = {};
   int vow = 0;
   cout << "Type a sentence: ";
   cin.getline(str, 50);
   for(int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i){
       switch (str[i]){
           case 'a':
           case 'e':
           case 'i':
           case 'o':
           case 'u': vow++;
       }
   }
   cout << "There are " << vow << " vowels in the string " << str;
   return 0;
}
```

Or, using `std::string` instead of `char[]`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   string str;
   int vow = 0;
   cout << "Type a sentence: ";
   getline(cin, str);
   for(size_t i = 0; i < str.size(); ++i){
       switch (str[i]){
           case 'a':
           case 'e':
           case 'i':
           case 'o':
           case 'u': vow++;
       }
   }
   cout << "There are " << vow << " vowels in the string " << str;
   return 0;
}
```